# Why Does SharePoint External Content Item Picker Not Select Item When OK is Pressed?

Tags: sharepoint, bcs, bdc, external-contenttype

I have a simple test scenario set up with 2 SQL Server tables.

```html
TEST_MainTable
ID  Name    LookupValue
1   Blue    1
2   Red 2
3   Green   3
4   Yellow  2

TEST_LookupTable
ID  Description
1   Value A
2   Value B
3   Value C
4   Value D
5   Value E
```

I had to use Code Snippet to get the formatting of my table data to be readable above.  Sorry, I'm a newbie at posting on this site.

I created a SharePoint External Content Type with all operations for both tables.

I created an association that maps the LoopkupValue column of TEST_MainTable to the ID of TEST_LookupTable.

I can create an external list for both content types and see and manipulate the data.

The problem is with the picker.  When I use New Item or Edit Item, I can manually type an ID in the LookupValue field and hit the validation button and get the underline showing it validated my input.   But if I open the picker and pick one of the lookup codes from the list and then hit the OK button in the picker, nothing happens.  If I wait about a minute, the picker will go blank and the message "Connection has been reset" is displayed.

I have been trying everything I can think of for several days now to no avail.  I have removed and recreated the ECT countless times.   Recycled the app pool of the site.   Tried it with out a foreign key on the SQL table.  It makes no sense to me why the validation button will immediately underline the value (or give a red error message if the value is invalid) when pressed, but the picker will not load the item into the field when a selection is made and the OK is clicked.   I am using SP Designer to do all the work.   I have also gone into the model in Central Admin after creating the ECT and given Selectable in Clients permission to all Authenticated users on both ECTs.

Comment: The issue appears to be permissions.  The ULS log is logging a 401 for the picker "because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication".   Yet, it gets the list contents and does the validation.  It just throws a 401 when I try to pick the item from the picker.   I have tried changing the connection settings to use all of the authentication methods offered, but it does the same thing in all circumstances, except if I use "User's Identity" the list won't display and I get an error that it is trying to connect with anonymous instead of my windows account.

Comment: SOLVED - This has been resolved with the help of Microsoft and our network team. Our SharePoint admin installed a cert and changed the site to use https instead of http. The picker is now working correctly.